# How can checkbox filter be set with IronPython in Spotfire?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a column that is set as a checkbox filter which has two values ("Refund" and "EMPTY").  I'd like to set that  filter to have only the "Refund" box checked, but I can't find out how to set it.

How is this done easily in IronPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'm setting the checkbox filters.  TOH to @Niko and @Jacek Sierajewski for the "(Empty)" hint for cb filter settings!

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import Filters as filters
strTtype= Document.Properties['Ttype']
FilterSelection = Document.Data.Filterings["Main Scheme"]
cbfRefund = Document.FilteringSchemes[FilterSelection][Document.Data.Tables["Transaction Data"]]["Refund Transaction"].As[filters.CheckBoxFilter]()
if strTtype=="Refund":
    for CheckBoxValue in cbfRefund.Values:
        cbfRefund.Uncheck(CheckBoxValue)
        if CheckBoxValue == "Refund":
            cbfRefund.Check(CheckBoxValue)
            cbfRefund.IncludeEmpty=False#This clears the "(Empty)" checkbox
```

Answer (score 4):

Set Filters Programatically (from a text input field)

- You have an input field in a text area (colname document property)
- You can pass multiple values (space separated) to the filter from the text area input field.
- You want to take the value from this text field and pass the value to a filter named 'Site Name'
- The filter in the filter palnel is a ListBoxFilter

[image]

```
import Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters as filters
import Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters.ListBoxFilter
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import FilterTypeIdentifiers
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataPropertyClass
from System import String
myPanel = Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel
myFilter= myPanel.TableGroups[0].GetFilter("Site Name")
lbFilter = myFilter.FilterReference.As[filters.ListBoxFilter]()
lbFilter.IncludeAllValues=False
strVals = Document.Properties["colname"]
if strVals!=String.Empty:
  lbFilter.SetSelection(strVals.split())
else:
  lbFilter.Reset()
```

Reference: 
http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2014/03/change-filters-programatically-from.html

Comment: @Keng, the important part of this is the line `lbFilter.IncludeAllValues=False`, which maybe should be called `lblFilter.IsEmptyChecked`. setting to `True` would tick the **(Empty)** box.